# Remove &thinsp; from Ruby String

Tags: ruby

i am try to parse some data and meet trouble with clean a   symbol. I knew that this is just a "space" but i realy got trouble to clean it from string
my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('my_page.hmtl')
price = page.search('#product_buy .price').text.to_s.gsub(/\s+/, "").gsub(" ","").gsub("&thinsp;", "")
puts price
```

And as result i always got "4 162" - with dat spaces. Don't know what to do.
Help please who meet this issue previously. Thank you

Comment: you should add the raw data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML escape codes don't mean anything to Ruby's regex engine. Looking for `"&thinsp;"` will look for those literal characters, not a thin space. Instead, versions of Ruby >= 1.8 support Unicode in strings, meaning that you can use the Unicode code point corresponding to a thin space to make your substitution. The Unicode code point for a thin space is `0x2009`, meaning that you can reference it in a Ruby string as `\u2009`.

Additionally, instead of calling `some_string.gsub('some_string', '')`, you can just call `some_string.delete('some_string')`.

Note that this isn't appropriate for all situations, because `delete` removes all instances of all characters appearing in the intersection of its arguments, while `gsub` will remove only segments matching the pattern provided. For example, `'hellohi'.gsub('hello', '') == "hi"`, while `'hellohi'.delete('hello') == 'i')`.

In your specific case, I'd use something like:

```
price = page.search('#product_buy .price').text.delete('\u2009\s')
```

Comment: thx for a tip, but seems like delete('\u2009\s') remove last symbol form line, not &thinsp; In real example,  i has "4&thinsp;162" and after delete('\u2009\s') i got "4 16" (at screen) and "4&thinsp;16"...

Comment: i found soution... .delete("\u2009") no need "\s". Thank you very much that directed me at correct solution.

Comment: @Sveredyuk No problem at all. I originally included the "\s" because it was part of the code sample you provided, but I'm glad you were able to figure that part out.